# Asking for HTTP/2 Stwitching Protocols in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, curl, nginx, http2

I'm trying to check if a http service supports HTTP/2 using a python 3 script.
Unfortunately, after many research and a lot of time spent on my script, I don't perform it.

Here what I have:

```
import sys
import http.client as HttpClient

h2c = {
  "User-agent": 'python/' + str(sys.version.split()[0]),
  "Connection": "Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings",
  "Upgrade": "h2c",
  "HTTP2-Settings": "AAMAAABkAAQAAP__",
  "Accept": "*/*"
}

c = HttpClient.HTTPSConnection(ip, port) # IP and port given in arguments
c.request('HEAD', '/', None, h2c)
r = c.getresponse()
# Print result (see below)
```

I know it exists [hyper](https://hyper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) but I don't always want SSL and currently certificate verification cannot be disabled with *hyper*

Here an example of my script running on localhost :

```
➜  http2 git:(master) ✗ python3 main.py -i localhost -p 443

HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Upgrade: h2c
User-agent: python/3.4.2
Accept: */*
Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAAQAAP__

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.9.12
Date: Tue, 22 Mar 2016 15:05:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 867
Last-Modified: Mon, 21 Mar 2016 10:03:18 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "56efc6e6-363"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

I checked and HTTP/2 is enable on my nginx server (with `curl --http2`)

If someone has an idea to force the server to reply HTTP 101 ...

Comment: ngnix does not support upgrade to HTTP/2 on plain text, see https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/816 and https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/808. And no support means that you cannot enforce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/2 can be negotiated in 2 ways: via TLS by means of ALPN or via clear-text HTTP/1.1 upgrade.

What you are doing here is a mix of the two methods: you are using a TLS connection and sending a HTTP/1.1 upgrade.

What you should do instead is to use the TLS connection, specify the ALPN extension with the list of protocols supported by the client (in your case, at least `h2`), then - if the server accepts to speak HTTP/2 - start sending directly HTTP/2 frames (not the HTTP/1.1 upgrade).

I am no Python expert, but it is possible to specify the ALPN protocols, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187470/tls-alpn-in-python-2-7) and [here](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/ALPN-Status).

You also want to look at [other Python projects](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) that implemented HTTP/2.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My fault, I misread the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7540#section-3.1) and in fact, they speak using the TLS connection, specify the ALPN extension.

Comment: However, we must use Python 3.5 to benefit from the function `set_alpn_protocols`, but I am dependant on 3.4 (my script needs of running on any PC without installing python from source, only thanks to apt package manager). Any suggestions?

Comment: I managed to do what I want thanks to `set_npn_protocols`. It is not recommanded in the RFC7540 but I'll use it until I can update python via the package manager. Thanks for your help!